# Finding the least upper bound for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, upper-lower-bounds

Define $f(1) = 10$ and $f(n) = f(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) + f(\lfloor n/3\rfloor) + 17n$.

Find the smallest value $k$ so that $f(n) \leq kn$ for all $n$.

---

I plugged in $f(1)$ into the function, which lead me to $2 \cdot f(0) + 17 = 10,$  so $f(0) = -7/2$.

Then I calculated $f(2) = f(1) + f(0) + 34 = 10 -7/2 + 34 =40.5$

Also $f(3) = f(1) + f(1) + 17(3) = 71$ and $f(4) = f(2) + f(1) + 17(4) = 118.5$

I don't see a clear pattern. I think it oscillates back and forth, but I can't get anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In $f\left(3\right)=f\left(1\right)+f\left(1\right)+17\left(3\right)$, you forgot to add $17\left(3\right)$.

Comment: i fixed the mistakes.

Comment: There is still a mistake. You wrote $17$ rather than $17\left(3\right)$. $f\left(3\right)\ne37$.

Comment: It looks as if $f$ is increasing with respect to $n$, so if $m\le n$, then $f\left(m\right)\le f\left(n\right)$. So,

$$f\left(n\right)=f\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+f\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)+17n\le f\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)+17n.$$

You can use this to find an upper-bound for the right-hand side of that inequality.

Comment: $f(6n)=f(3n)+f(2n)+102n$. I wrote a short program to compute $\lfloor f(n)/n\rfloor$ and found that between $n=5\times10^9$ and $n=1\times 10^{10}$ the value hangs at $101$ making the $102n$ look very interesting.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales awesome! The recurrence relation $T\left(n\right)=T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)+17n$ gives $T\left(n\right)=102n$, which was the upper-bound for $f\left(n\right)$.